# Major/Minor GC not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection, unicorn

I was debugging a memory leak in my Ruby app (**Ruby 2.1.2**). While gathering GC stat for unicorn master process over the time I found out that major & minor GC count is not changing. Here below is sample GC stat:

> {:count=>273, :heap_used=>10181, :heap_length=>12252, :heap_increment=>2071, :heap_live_slot=>4113806, :heap_free_slot=>35946, :heap_final_slot=>0, :heap_swept_slot=>655582, :heap_eden_page_length=>10181, :heap_tomb_page_length=>0, :total_allocated_object=>132076290, :total_freed_object=>127962484, :malloc_increase=>164098552, :malloc_limit=>30949538, **:minor_gc_count=>260, :major_gc_count=>13**, :remembered_shady_object=>19831, :remembered_shady_object_limit=>29756, :old_object=>699918, :old_object_limit=>1069156, :oldmalloc_increase=>185902224, :oldmalloc_limit=>58937052}

After approx 7 hours:

> {:count=>273, :heap_used=>23353, :heap_length=>39695,
>   :heap_increment=>16342, :heap_live_slot=>9482797,
>   :heap_free_slot=>35840, :heap_final_slot=>0, :heap_swept_slot=>655582,
>   :heap_eden_page_length=>23353, :heap_tomb_page_length=>0,
>   :total_allocated_object=>137445281, :total_freed_object=>127962484,
>   :malloc_increase=>663823560, :malloc_limit=>30949538,
>   **:minor_gc_count=>260, :major_gc_count=>13**,
>   :remembered_shady_object=>19831,
>   :remembered_shady_object_limit=>29756, :old_object=>699918,
>   :old_object_limit=>1069156, :oldmalloc_increase=>685627232,
>   :oldmalloc_limit=>58937052}

As per my understanding, if :oldmalloc_increase crosses :oldmalloc_limit then major GC is triggered. Also if :malloc_increase crosses :malloc_limit a minor GC is triggered.

In my case both oldmalloc_increase & malloc_increase is exceeding limit still GC is not triggered.

Can anyone please help me with below queries:

1. Why Minor/Major GC is not triggered?
2. malloc_increase & oldmalloc_increase is continuously increasing which is causing OOM issue. If I restart my app then both these values are resetting to normal range. Does it mean my Ruby app is leaking memory? Is memory not getting freed because GC is not running?

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to find a specific answer here because these sorts of things are highly situational. Does the leak also manifest in another Ruby implementation like JRuby or Ruby 2.5? You're going to need to try and identify the source of this problem. Ruby 2.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/04/01/support-of-ruby-2-1-has-ended/) and you should upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @tadman, thanks for your response. I have not tested it with other Ruby implementations/versions as it's our production app and upgrading ruby version might require an upgrade for gems as well, we have a long list of gems being used.

Comment: Going from 2.1 to 2.5 should be pretty seamless, nothing really broke. It's usually upgrading the gems themselves that's a lot more fuss. I'd give it a shot as part of your diagnostics, even if just on your local machine.